# How do I Log out of Google Accounts, one at a time?

Tags: google-account, account-management, google-multi-login

I volunteer for many organizations, earning me several Google accounts to manage. The Multiple account sign-in feature built into Google is wonderful, except when I click Sign out, its signs out of all my accounts at once.

Is there a different way to just sign out of one account at a time? If there is, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I use Firefox's Multifox add-on http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/ to keep a separate window for each account to deal with special cases like Google Analytics etc. which do not have proper multiaccount support. Allocate one account per one window and they don't conflict. Might work for you too.

Comment: If using Chrome, use the MultiLogin extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/nknfhhmhoflkcijaodalbncnmidocced?hl=en

Comment: @JaydenLawson, that plug-in doesn't work for Gmail in my testing.

Comment: @Josh true. There's always an alternate version if you look around. Eg. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/ijfgglilaeakmoilplpcjcgjaoleopfi?hl=en

Comment: Oh and in Firefox, the solution in comment #1 is now easier with the now built-in firefox containers feature. Each container can have its own login or logins active.

Comment: Idea: Has anyone tried examining and editing or selectively deleting google cookies in order to do what the OP is asking? I’m guessing that by comparing cookies when logged in in different scenarios one might be able to figure this out… Then one could make a plug-in to do it. Worst-case scenario a specialized password manager could achieve the desired result through brute force: By logging out and then logging in each the accounts but the desired one(s). (And stackexchange is CC-By, so anybody can use my idea?)

Comment: I found a solution to this recently that works at least for gmail (though it is rather hacky): 1) open an incognito window, 2) sign into the account that you want to log out of, 3) then click the "Sign out of all other web sessions" button, which will sign you out of **only** that account on the original browser, 4) now, close the incognito window (which will finish signing out of that account).

[Posting as a comment instead of answer as I don't have sufficient reputation to answer.]

Comment: I don't see this "sign out of all other web sessions" button. Could you post your comment as a step-by-step answer with screenshots?

Comment: I suppose what interests me is *why* Google has designed Chrome and Google accounts to be this way. Is there some sort of security principle at work here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**You cannot** - This is not supported as of now, and I don't think there could be any alternate solution until Google offers an improvement to its Multiple-sign-on capability.

Google's multiple sign-on capability helps you manage more than one of your accounts simultaneously. Signing-in to a different account when you're already signed-in, would link both your accounts (on the client side). And on each additional sign-in, each of the accounts are linked to one other. Signing-out from one account would implicitly mean that you sign-out from all your accounts (similar to a domino effect).

Google must support unlinking of two signed-in accounts for you being able to selectively signing-out of an account, but retaining the signed-in status of other accounts.

Comment: This is sad news. Can you give me a reference to where you found that info so I can verify its validity and accept your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know of any official statement from Google. But you can find many such complaints & details here.. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gmail/multiple$20sign$20in

Comment: Yeah, see, this is incorrect (or at least incomplete).  I logged in to my personal account while already logged in to my work account, and _never linked them_ - yet, I still see the buggy behavior that the OP describes.

Comment: How did you manage to log into another account without logging out of the first account or linking them using multiple sign-on.

Comment: Can you state your sources or otherwise provide evidence? I'm pretty sure signing in to two accounts does not link them in any way.

Comment: When I said linked, I meant listed together on the client side. I use Chrome and all accounts are listed via the account chooser during sign in. And this was more than two years ago. Right now they do support listing accounts via the account chooser even on log-off. Of course you would need to choose something like "remember me".

Comment: I provided an edit to the answer, as its highly misleading that logging into multiple accounts links them together. As the author stated in the comments, they meant "on the client" so I added the edit.

Comment: Idea!: <Moved to comment on question>

Answer (score 13):

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en

Signing out

If you choose to sign out of any account while using multiple sign-in, you will be signed out of all your accounts. To resume using multiple sign-in, you will need sign in to one account and then use the Add Account option to sign in to your other account(s).

Answer (score 3):

While a log out does sign you out of all linked Google Accounts, you can use Incognito (or private) mode to open additional accounts (one at a time) that you do not want to remain logged in with. Alternatively, use multiple browsers to accomplish NEARLY what you want by logging in with another set of Google accounts.

I use 4 Google Accounts at once with Chrome (there may be an account limit to how many can be logged in) and then use Chrome's Incognito (Private browsing) mode to open additional accounts as I need.

Not the best way, but does work around the current process.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, as described [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-sign-out-of-one-google-account). To sign out of one Google account when using multiple accounts, follow these steps:

1. Open the Google app on your phone.
2. Tap on your profile picture and select the Manage your Google Account option.
3. Switch to the Security tab.
4. Go to Your devices section.
5. Tap on the Manage devices button.
6. Select the device you want to sign out of.
7. Tap on the three-dotted icon.
8. Select the Sign out option.

This also works from your Google account on another desktop device. I have followed the instructions and it worked for me. However, while it signs you out, it doesn't remove the account from the list of accounts available - it simply means you'll need to log in when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found Chrome has a new feature for logging into different users. To do it:

1. Open settings
2. Click on Signed in as *_*_...
3. Under the "Users" section, click add new user.

Now I can be logged into as many Google drives as I want, each with their own Chrome instance! To see which window is what, look for the little avatar that you chose in the top left corner near your first Tab.

Official link: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824

Comment: This is about signing in, not signing out as asked in the question