# Sign out one at a time from multiple Gmail accounts in Chrome

Tags: google-account, google-chrome, google-multi-login

Anyone has solution how to sign out one account at a time instead of signing out all at one time in Gmail?

Because, for example, I use Gmail account A to Sync my whole data, like Chrome, Google Keep, Contacts, everything. Accounts B, C, D, E—I use these Gmail accounts for many other purposes. I want to login and out whenever I want without affecting account A.

Comment: I like Chrome and Gmail, so i need answer for this problem!

Comment: Presumably you can't sign-in to more than one account at a time either? Have you "delegated" accounts B, C, D and E?

Comment: Of course, we can signin more than one account at a time, and when we click at Userprof in gmail, pop will show multiple accounts signedin and we can do the same activity with all google services. but, when signout, this action is doing to all accounts at a time. we don't have individual signout options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Log out of Google Accounts, one at a time?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33701/how-do-i-log-out-of-google-accounts-one-at-a-time)

Comment: I thought so too initially, but this question seems to be about Chrome sync, not website sync.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward approach is to make a separate Chrome user profile for each Google login.

You can keep these Chrome user profiles logged into Google, and just open/close their windows as needed.

Comment: thanks. But, In that case, chrome will consume system speed a l a lot, one unique account itself dominating my system, if do multiple, i can imagine how difficult it would be. But, i am managing with Lastpass, its helping me greatly. I signout and singin immediately without typing username and pass. Lastpass helping two ways, managing this prob and saving bunch of passwords we use hundreds of webs in daily life.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to sign out of individual Gmail/Google accounts, it requires temporarily removing access to Google Chrome in "Google Apps":

You can remove your account from one of your devices, even if you don’t have that device with you. You’ll be signed out from any computer you’ve used before, including the one you’re using now.

On your computer, open Chrome.
Go to your Google Account to manage apps with access to your account.
Under "Google apps," click Google Chrome and then Remove access.

Sign back in to allow Google Chrome access again.

Here's a link to Google's Support about it https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9159867?hl=en.