# How do I sign out of a single Google account?

Tags: google-account, google-multi-login

I am trying to sign out of a Google account I have on Chrome, running on macOS.

I do not see a "sign out," "log out," or a "remove account" button anywhere in the account dropdown. I only can see a "sign out of all accounts" button, which I do not want to do—I want to sign out of a specific account and remove it. I have tried going to myaccount.google.com, but it doesn't show anything relevant there. I have tried everything I could find in other answers, but it seems like none of them are up to date. Perhaps the ability to sign out of a single account has been removed?

Comment: Related [Sign out one at a time from multiple Gmail accounts in Chrome](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/83037/88163)

Comment: Sometimes big companies think they are really smart and turn up to be most foolish. What kind of user is this who cannot log out? obviously, there may be benefits for them like once logged in they may collect data from machines. Anyhow it's the worst user experience. Similarly, if you observe a Samsung keypad, they do not provide a negate sign. lol they made it too positive

Comment: I have an answer to this question but not enough reputation on this stack to post it, I believe there to be a workaround that doesn't requite multiple devices.

Comment: @Some_Guy cool, mind sharing it here in the comments? If you want I could make a post with it and mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Go to google.com.  Find your profile icon on the top right.  Click on it. Select the account which you want out of.  Use the downward caret to expose the menu for that accouont.  Select "remove".

Comment: "Use the downward caret to expose the menu for that account" unfortunately I lost you here. Which downwards caret?

Comment: Follow steps in this post:
https://www.gadgetsnow.com/how-to/how-to-sign-out-of-just-one-google-account/articleshow/89539765.cms

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*"Perhaps the ability to sign out of a single account has been removed?"*

**I am afraid you are correct**.

It has nothing to do with the kind of the operating system (Mac, Windows, Linux etc) you use.
It also has nothing to do with the browser you use (being Chrome, FireFox, Safari etc).

**It is ALL about the browser you are logged into from**.

As per the [official Google site](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977):

> ---
>
> **Sign out**
>
> **When you sign out of one account, you also sign out of all your accounts on that browser**:
>
> 1. On your computer, go to a Google page, like www.google.com.
> 2. On the top right, select your profile image or initial.
> 3. On the menu, choose `Sign out`.
>
> ---

***Your future behaviour as a workaround***
Try logging in using a private/incognito window.

---

Useful tip

- *What a default account is*
  In many cases, your default account is the one you signed in with first. On mobile devices, your default account can vary depending on your device's operating system and the apps you use.

Answer (score 8):

Posts here and elsewhere allude to a workaround - just for clarity, here is one possible approach with full details.

The basic idea is to log into the account on a separate device, and use Google's security interface to log the account out of the original device.

1. Log into the account in an incognito, private or guest browser session on a totally separate device.  Note that it must be a separate device, not just a separate browser, because Google will recognize the device itself, and won't let you log out the same device that you are on.
2. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity (or click your avatar icon > Security > Your devices).
3. Locate the initial device that you were using and click on it.
4. Click Sign out

Comment: +1 I was surprised to confirm that I really did need to use a separate device rather than just a separate browser.

Comment: It is now possible to do it within the same browser, just using incognito mode (at least on macOS/Safari). Unfortunately, the account persists on the list with "Session expired" next to it. Ugh.....

Comment: Windows 11 + Chrome logging out via incognito: now tested working too, and also leaves the annoying "Session expired" account there.

Answer (score 0):

https://accounts.google.com/

go here and click remove account

Comment: I can't see an option like that. Are you seeing something I'm not?

Comment: It's in the "Security" tab under "Your devices" https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity click on a device and click sign out

Comment: The "Sign out" button is only available for devices other than your current device.